# Chrome steps in debug mode are very slow

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

Since version 1.38 doing steps in debug mode with Chrome work very slow, while when using Chromium its work fine. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Chrome version : Version 80.0.3962.2 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)

`VS code launch.json`:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "Chromium",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chromium against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--new-window",
      "-user-data-dir=\"/${workspaceFolder}/DevProfile\"",
      "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
      "--disable-background-networking"
    ]
  },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Chrome 4200",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeExecutable" : "/opt/google/chrome-unstable/chrome",
        // "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/build/**/*" ]
        "sourceMaps": true,
        // "trace":
```

Comment: Do you mean there's a several seconds delay before breakpoint is triggered and before you step through to next statement?

Comment: Yes, even if you just trying to do one step, it cat took few seconds, until you can do one more step

Comment: Then I got the same in 79+, it makes debugging absolutely unbearable. I use a portable Chromium 78 for development until the regression is fixed.